# How many ayaths are there in Al-Quran?

Tags: quran, ayah, uloom-al-quran

I heard that there are totally 6666 ayats in Al-Quran.

But, I counted in my own Quran and it has less than that.

What is the actual number of ayats in Al-Quran?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 6236 in total (not counting the basmalas at start). You can get a copy of Quran in text file from [tanzil](http://tanzil.net/download). Just download a copy and check the number of lines/entries to see for yourself.

Comment: I have big doubts whether your statement "(not counting the basmalas at start)" is correct, as in surat al-Fatiha the basmalah is a separated verse in the kufi count and that's the count which has 6236 verses!

Answer (score 18):

The total number of ayats in the Quran is 6236.

Details below:

```
|-------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+------|
| Chapter No. | Surah Name    | Accepted Variant Names                          | Ayat |
|-------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+------|
|           1 | al-Fatihah    | al-Fatiha                                       |    7 |
|           2 | al-Baqarah    | al-Baqara                                       |  286 |
|           3 | al-Imran      |                                                 |  200 |
|           4 | an-Nisa'      | an-Nisa, al-Nisa                                |  176 |
|           5 | al-Ma'idah    | al-Ma'idah, al-Maidah, al-Maida                 |  120 |
|           6 | al-An`am      | al-Anam, al-Anaam, al-Annam                     |  165 |
|           7 | al-A`raf      | al-Araf                                         |  206 |
|           8 | al-Anfal      |                                                 |   75 |
|           9 | at-Taubah     | at-Tauba, Baraa'                                |  129 |
|          10 | Yunus         |                                                 |  109 |
|          11 | Hud           |                                                 |  123 |
|          12 | Yusuf         |                                                 |  111 |
|          13 | ar-Ra`d       | ar-Rad                                          |   43 |
|          14 | Ibrahim       |                                                 |   52 |
|          15 | al-Hijr       |                                                 |   99 |
|          16 | an-Nahl       |                                                 |  128 |
|          17 | al-Isra'      | al-Isra, Bani Isra'il, Bani Israil              |  111 |
|          18 | al-Kahf       |                                                 |  110 |
|          19 | Maryam        |                                                 |   98 |
|          20 | Ta Ha         | Ta-Ha                                           |  135 |
|          21 | al-Anbiya'    | al-Anbiya                                       |  112 |
|          22 | al-Hajj       |                                                 |   78 |
|          23 | al-Mu'minun   | al-Muminun, al-Mumenoon                         |  118 |
|          24 | an-Nur        | an-Noor                                         |   64 |
|          25 | al-Furqan     |                                                 |   77 |
|          26 | ash-Shu`ara'  | ash-Shuara                                      |  227 |
|          27 | an-Naml       |                                                 |   93 |
|          28 | al-Qasas      |                                                 |   88 |
|          29 | al-`Ankabut   | al-Ankabut, al-Ankaboott                        |   69 |
|          30 | ar-Rum        | ar-Rum, ar-Room                                 |   60 |
|          31 | Luqman        | Lukman                                          |   34 |
|          32 | as-Sajdah     | as-Sajda, al-Mala'ikah, al-Malaikah, al-Malaika |   30 |
|          33 | al-Ahzab      |                                                 |   73 |
|          34 | Saba'         | Saba                                            |   54 |
|          35 | Fatir         | al-Fatir                                        |   45 |
|          36 | Ya Sin        | Ya Seen                                         |   83 |
|          37 | as-Saffat     | as-Saaffat, al-Saffat                           |  182 |
|          38 | Sad           |                                                 |   88 |
|          39 | az-Zumar      |                                                 |   75 |
|          40 | Ghafir        |                                                 |   85 |
|          41 | Fussilat      | Ha Mim Sajdah, Ha Mim Sajda                     |   54 |
|          42 | ash-Shura     |                                                 |   53 |
|          43 | az-Zukhruf    | al-Zukhruf                                      |   89 |
|          44 | ad-Dukhan     | al-Dukhan                                       |   59 |
|          45 | al-Jathiyah   | al-Jathiya                                      |   37 |
|          46 | al-Ahqaf      |                                                 |   35 |
|          47 | Muhammad      | al-Qital                                        |   38 |
|          48 | al-Fath       |                                                 |   29 |
|          49 | al-Hujurat    | al-Hujraat                                      |   18 |
|          50 | Qaf           |                                                 |   45 |
|          51 | adh-Dhariyat  | al-Dhariyat, az-Zariyat                         |   60 |
|          52 | at-Tur        | al-Tur                                          |   49 |
|          53 | an-Najm       | al-Najm                                         |   62 |
|          54 | al-Qamar      |                                                 |   55 |
|          55 | ar-Rahman     |                                                 |   78 |
|          56 | al-Waqi`ah    | al-Waqiah, al-Waqia                             |   96 |
|          57 | al-Hadid      |                                                 |   29 |
|          58 | al-Mujadilah  | al-Mujadila                                     |   22 |
|          59 | al-Hashr      |                                                 |   24 |
|          60 | al-Mumtahinah | al-Mumtahina, al-Mumtahanah                     |   13 |
|          61 | as-Saff       |                                                 |   14 |
|          62 | al-Jumu`ah    | al-Jumua, al-Jum`ah, al-Jumuah                  |   11 |
|          63 | al-Munafiqun  | al-Munafiqoon                                   |   11 |
|          64 | at-Taghabun   |                                                 |   18 |
|          65 | at-Talaq      |                                                 |   12 |
|          66 | at-Tahrim     |                                                 |   12 |
|          67 | al-Mulk       |                                                 |   30 |
|          68 | al-Qalam      |                                                 |   52 |
|          69 | al-Haqqah     | al-Haqqa                                        |   52 |
|          70 | al-Ma`arij    | al-Maarij                                       |   44 |
|          71 | Nuh           | Nooh                                            |   28 |
|          72 | al-Jinn       |                                                 |   28 |
|          73 | al-Muzammil   |                                                 |   20 |
|          74 | al-Mudathir   | al-Muddaththir                                  |   56 |
|          75 | al-Qiyamah    | al-Qiyama                                       |   40 |
|          76 | al-Insan      | ad-Dahr                                         |   31 |
|          77 | al-Mursalat   |                                                 |   50 |
|          78 | an-Naba'      | an-Naba                                         |   40 |
|          79 | an-Nazi'at    | an-Nazi'at, an-Naziat, al-Naziat                |   46 |
|          80 | `Abasa        | Abasa                                           |   42 |
|          81 | at-Takwir     |                                                 |   29 |
|          82 | al-Infitar    |                                                 |   19 |
|          83 | al-Mutaffifin | at-Tatfif                                       |   36 |
|          84 | al-Inshiqaq   |                                                 |   25 |
|          85 | al-Buruj      | al-Burooj                                       |   22 |
|          86 | at-Tariq      | al-Tariq                                        |   17 |
|          87 | al-A`la       | al-Ala                                          |   19 |
|          88 | al-Ghashiyah  | al-Ghashiya                                     |   26 |
|          89 | al-Fajr       |                                                 |   30 |
|          90 | al-Balad      |                                                 |   20 |
|          91 | ash-Shams     | al-Shams                                        |   15 |
|          92 | al-Layl       | al-Lail                                         |   21 |
|          93 | ad-Dhuha      | ad-Duha, al-Duha                                |   11 |
|          94 | al-Inshirah   | al-Inshira, ash-Sharh                           |    8 |
|          95 | at-Tin        | al-Tin                                          |    8 |
|          96 | al-`Alaq      | al-Alaq                                         |   19 |
|          97 | al-Qadr       |                                                 |    5 |
|          98 | al-Baiyinah   | al-Baiyina, al-Bayyinah                         |    8 |
|          99 | az-Zalzalah   | al-Zilzal                                       |    8 |
|         100 | al-`Adiyat    | al-Adiyat                                       |   11 |
|         101 | al-Qari`ah    | al-Qariah, al-Qaria                             |   11 |
|         102 | at-Takathur   |                                                 |    8 |
|         103 | al-`Asr       | al-Asr                                          |    3 |
|         104 | al-Humazah    | al-Humaza                                       |    9 |
|         105 | al-Fil        |                                                 |    5 |
|         106 | Quraysh       | Qurayish, al-Quraysh                            |    4 |
|         107 | al-Ma'un      | al-Ma`un, al-Maun                               |    7 |
|         108 | al-Kauthar    | al-Kauther                                      |    3 |
|         109 | al-Kafirun    | al-Kafiroon                                     |    6 |
|         110 | an-Nasr       |                                                 |    3 |
|         111 | al-Masad      | al-Masadd, al-Lahab                             |    5 |
|         112 | al-Ikhlas     | at-Tauhid, at-Tawhid                            |    4 |
|         113 | al-Falaq      |                                                 |    5 |
|         114 | an-Nas        |                                                 |    6 |
|-------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+------|
|             |               |                                                 | 6236 |
|-------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+------|
```

Comment: What surah is surah an'nasr? I haven't even heard of it nor I see it inside the Quran.

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan  victoryالنصر

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan You need to look harder, it's one of the shortest - and therefore, most frequently memorised - surahs. 

https://quran.com/110

Answer (score 9):

The question is not properly defined. It would be better if you pointed out:

**According which count you want the number of ayat in the qur'an?**

Because only for a few surahs ([al-Mulk](http://sunnah.com/urn/731280), and [al-Fatiha](http://sunnah.com/urn/731090)) there is a fixed number of ayat known (from ahadith, check the links) therefore the number differs between the different counts, which are a result of ijtihad of the Sahaba () and the Tabi'yn (), for example: have they considered the basmalah (bismi Llahi ar-rahmani ar-rahim بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم ) as a separate verse or not? Where did the Prophet () make a pause (this was the point where a Verse finished)? How many times they witnessed him do so? and how this pause has been qualified, based on these occasions.:

So are you talking about the Kufi (referring to al-Kufa) count (the most common as the riwaya of Hafs from 'Assim is the most common riwaya/qira'a and 'Assim is a Kufi rawy) or the Madani (referring to Medina) count or the Mekki (referring to Mekkah) count etc. ? For example [ayat al Kursi](http://quran.com/2/255)  is in the Madani count divided into 2 Verses!

> Allah - there is no deity except Him, the Ever-Living, the Sustainer
> of [all] existence. Neither drowsiness overtakes Him nor sleep. To Him
> belongs whatever is in the heavens and whatever is on the earth. Who
> is it that can intercede with Him except by His permission? He knows
> what is [presently] before them and what will be after them, and they
> encompass not a thing of His knowledge except for what He wills.(*NEW*
> *VERSE in Madani Count*)
> His Kursi extends over the heavens and the
> earth, and their preservation tires Him not. And He is the Most High,
> the Most Great.

And for those who don't count al-Basmalah as a Verse they reach 7 Verses in surat al-Fatiha by dividing the last Verse, as follows:

> (6)The path of those upon whom You have bestowed favor, not of those
> who have evoked [Your] anger or (7) of those who are astray.
> ([1:7](http://legacy.quran.com/1/7))

The Kufi count might have the most Verses because they were the only ones to count the basmallah and also used to count the Muqatta'at (المقطعات) in the 19 surahs beginning with them as a separate verse, which others don't!

**The surahs on which there's a consensus in the verse counts**

In his al-Kamil fil Qira'at الكامل في القراءات العشر والأربعين الزائدة عليها p.120 - 130 abu al-Qassim al-Hudhali أبو القاسم الهذلي showed the differences in the counts in-depth (more details than I will display here) and showed the verses of each surah that might not apply to the general ruling (for example a Madani verse in a Makki surah and vice versa). Here is just a list of surahs where all counts are in consensus about the number of verses:

1. Al-Fatiha (Surah number 1, number of verses 7)
2. Yussuf (s 12, v 111)
3. Al-Hijr (s 15, v 99)
4. Al-Furqan (s 25, v 70)
5. Al-Ahzaab (Surah number 33, number of verses 73)
6. Al-Fath (s 48, v 29)
7. Al-Hujurat (s 49, v 18)
8. Qaf (s 50, v 45)
9. A-Dhariyat (s 51, v 60)
10. Al-Qamar (Surah number 54, number of verses 55)
11. Al-Hashr (s 59, v 24)
12. Al-Mumtahana (s 60, v 13)
13. As-Saff (s 61, v 14)
14. Al-Jumu'ah (s 62, v 11)
15. Al-Munafiqoon (Surah number 63, number of verses 11)
16. At-Tagahbun (s 64, v 18)
17. Al-Qalam (s 68, v 52)
18. Al-Insaan (s 76, v 31)
19. Al-Infitar (s 82, v 19)
20. Al-Mutaffiyn (Surah number 83, number of verses 36)
21. Al-A'laa (s 87 , v 19)
22. Al-Ghashiyah (s 88, v 26)
23. Al-Balad (s 90, v 20)
24. Al-Lail (s 92, v 21)
25. A-Doha (Surah number  93, number of verses 11)
26. A-Sharh (s 94, v 8)
27. At-Tyn (s 95, v 8)
28. At-Takathur (s 102, v 8)
29. Al-'Asr (3)
30. Al-Humazah (Surah number 104, number of verses 9)
31. Al-Fyl (s 105, v 5)
32. Al-Kawtar (s 108, v 3)
33. Al-Kafiroon (s 109, v 6)
34. An-Nasr (s 110, v 3)
35. Al-Masad (Surah number 111, number of verses 5)
36. Al-Falaq (s 113, v 5)

Note that surat al-Mulk is not mentioned in the above list as the Makki and the last Madani counts say it is 31 verses and have separated verse ([67:9](http://legacy.quran.com/67/9)) as follows:

> They will say," Yes, a warner had come to us, (9) but we denied and said, ' Allah has not sent down anything. You are not but in great error.' " (10)

**Number of verses in the qur'an according the known counts**

According the different [counts](https://mawdoo3.com/%D9%83%D9%85_%D8%B9%D8%AF%D8%AF_%D8%A2%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AA_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%B1%D8%A2%D9%86_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%B1%D9%8A%D9%85_%D9%88%D8%AD%D8%B1%D9%88%D9%81%D9%87_%D9%88%D8%B9%D8%AF%D8%AF_%D8%A3%D8%AD%D8%B2%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%87) they are:

- In the **Madani** (Medina) count the number is **6214** (in the 1st Madina count they were counted to be 6217) and
- in the **Kufi** (al-Kufa) count the number is **6236**
- in the **Makky** (Mekkah) count they are **6210**
- in the **Basry** (Basra) count **6214**
- in the count of **a-Shaam** (Damascus and its surroundings) **6226**

Abu al-Qassim al-Hudhali added a count from Homs/Hims

See also Fatwa's islamweb [#3635](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/3635/%D8%B9%D8%AF%D8%AF-%D9%83%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%88%D8%A2%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%88%D8%AD%D8%B1%D9%88%D9%81-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%B1%D8%A2%D9%86?) (on the number of words, letters and verses of the qur'an) , [#75878](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/75878/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AF%D9%86%D9%8A-%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D9%88%D9%81%D9%8A) (on the difference of the Madani and Kufi count which still can be witnessed in Moshafs) and [#173515](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/173515/%D8%B3%D8%A8%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D8%AE%D8%AA%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%81-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%A1-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%B9%D8%AF%D8%AF-%D8%A2%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%B1%D8%A2%D9%86) (on the reason for the differences in the counts) all in Arabic.

And Allah knows best!

Comment: Assalamualaikum why are there different verse counts?

Comment: @Afiq the post should explain it

Comment: The link doesn't work. It takes me to the site instead of the Fatwa.

Comment: @Afiq I've said the post not anything linked. I've updated the fatwa link the fatwa is only giving some general information.

Comment: This is a much better answer than the other answers here and deserves more upvotes, but it would really benefit from more direct sources for the claims made, especially for the different counts and where they come from.

Answer (score 6):

the "6666 verses" myth was likely introduced to scare off Christians from looking into Islam, by associating the Quran with the [devil's number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_of_the_Beast).

The total number of Ayats in the Quran is around 6,236.
The actual number may vary depending on what is counted as a complete Ayat.

and Allah knows best.

Comment: Assalaamu Alaikum, welcome to Islam.StackExchange.com. I thank you for posting an answer here. I request you to please go through [this faq](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/598/59) to get an idea of [writing great answers](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/598/59). If you make a claim of something, you should quote reliable references. Jazaakallah.

Comment: Actually, it is “666” devil’s number  and Islam does not want to scare anyone, but to call to the truth and to call others to greatest successes in this world and also in Hereafter.

Comment: Actually there are 6,666 verses in the quran according to muslim sources. Esack Farid, The Qur’an: A user’s guide, p.59
https://islamqa.org/hanafi/daruliftaa-birmingham/88370
"There are 114 chapters of the Holy Qur’an known in Arabic as “surah” and 6,666 verses known as “ayahs” of unequal length in the Qur’an. (Esack Farid, The Qur’an: A user’s guide, p.59). Imam Suyuti raḥimahullāh (may Allāh have mercy upon him) in his Itqaan has mentioned two opinions with regards to the number of verses in the Holy Qur’an. One opinion is 6,666 on the authority of Saaidah Aaisha"

Answer (score 4):

There are totally `6236` ayats in Al-Quran.

[Source](http://www.islam101.com/dawah/QuranStats.htm).

Answer (score 3):

Assalamu Alaykum brothers and sisters. I just counted it, and I got 6236. Allah and Allah's messenger knows best.

Comment: Welcome @user5055, please avoid duplicate answers.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the total of ayahs is due to some people count the Starting `Bismillah` in start of every Surah as a separate verse and others just count it once.

[This islamword.net link](http://www.islamworld.net/docs/quran.info.html) has a complete statistic gathered at one place. From the page

> Total No. of Verses 6236

Answer (score 0):

Number of ayat in the Al-Qur'an are 6236 ayat (without counting basmalah which are not be given number, there are 112 ayat).

Number of ayat in surah Al-Fatihah are 7 ayat, including basmalah (ayah number 1).

Comment: Welcome is [islam.se]. Please try to make sure your answer shares info that is not available in other answers. Please clarify *"there are 112 ayat"* and *"ayah number 1"*.

Comment: Your answer includes many mistakes as among 114 Sura in the Quran there's 113 times a basmalah in the Beginning not 112. And the Kufi count includes Basmalah so 6236 Verse would be including the Basmalah. Unless you made a new count and it was accepted by scholars, then you should give us a proof!