# Why is the same verse in 2:149 repeated in 2:150?

Tags: quran, tafseer, surat-al-baqarah

Assalamu Alaikum Brothers in Islam,

Can you please help me understand as to why in Surah Baqarah the verse 149 is repeated again in 150?

> So from wherever you go out [for prayer, O Muhammad] turn your face toward al- Masjid al-Haram, and indeed, it is the truth from your Lord. And Allah is not unaware of what you do. **[Surah Baqarah : 149]**

and

> And from wherever you go out [for prayer], turn your face toward al-Masjid al-Haram. And wherever you [believers] may be, turn your faces toward it in order that the people will not have any argument against you, except for those of them who commit wrong; so fear them not but fear Me. And [it is] so I may complete My favor upon you and that you may be guided.
>   **[Surah Baqarah : 150]**

Comment: [Qur'an is so concise but in surah rahman a single ayah repeated 31 times](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49742/quran-is-so-concise-but-in-surah-rahman-a-single-ayah-repeated-31-times) might be relvant.

Comment: @Medi1Saif ibn katheer explains it in his tafseer. And, when reciting the verses the repetition of "wa min 7aythu kharajta…" etc adds an emphasis that can be felt and is very profound, subhan allah.

Answer (score 0):

It may have some similar parts but not all and that s clear by the translation you have provided.

From just some interpretation (if there is a deeper meaning to both these verses please say so) it seems that surah al Baqarah 2:149 tells us to face al-Masjid al-Haram because it is truth from the Lord. Surah 2:150 tells us to face al-Masjid al-Haram but says numerous things like  fear Allah and that the people will not argue unless they wronged themselves and about Allah's favour.