# Ayas 59:1 and 61:1 of the Holy Quran seem like they are exactly the same? Why the duplication?

Tags: quran, tafseer, uloom-al-quran

I regularly read and study the Quran and when I encounter verses that seem to be duplicates turn out to differ by a few Arabic letters, which result in a slightly different meaning.  This is expected since Allah swtl would not waste words.  However, the verses 59:1 and 61:1 are letter for letter, exactly the same.  Why is this?  Other than the Bismillahs at the beginnings of each surah (except Tawbah), this is the only exact duplication I have seen.

Sabbaĥa Lillāh Mā Fī As-Samāwāti Wa Mā Fī Al-'Arđi ۖ Wa Huwa Al-`Azīzu Al-Ĥakīmu
061.001 Whatever is in the heavens and on earth, let it declare the Praises and Glory of God: for He is the Exalted in Might, the Wise.
سَبَّحَ لِلَّهِ مَا‌ فِي ‌ال‍‍سَّمَا‌و‍َ‍‌اتِ ‌وَمَا‌ فِي ‌الأَ‌رْ‍ضِ ۖ ‌وَهُوَ‌ ‌الْعَز‍ِ‍ي‍‍زُ‌‌الْحَكِيمُ

Comment: I'd say that your question ius at least addressed in [Qur'an is so concise, but in surah Rahman a single ayah is repeated 31 times](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49742/quran-is-so-concise-but-in-surah-rahman-a-single-ayah-repeated-31-times/49751#49751)