# In which Quranic verse is the word "Allah" mentioned the most times?

Tags: quran

In which Quranic verse is the word "Allah" mentioned the most times?? And what surah is that??

Comment: Please clarify your question. My guess is that you are asking in which verse the name of Allah has been mentioned with the greatest frequency? Are you considering just the word "Allah" or any of His Names?

Comment: The issue with such questions is that the verse count is based on ijtihad and there's a certain difference between scholars on this I know of at least 5 different counts! See also [How many ayaths are there in al-Qur'an?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5566/how-many-ayaths-are-there-in-al-quran/27464#27464)

Answer (score 4):

Running some code on the data from [corpus.quran.com](http://corpus.quran.com/qurandictionary.jsp?q=Alh) , the highest frequency of the name "Allah" appears  to be in the last verse of [Surah al-Muzzammil (73:20)](https://quran.com/73/20) where it occurs 7 times:

[image]

The next highest frequency seems to be 6 times in [Surah al-Baqarah (2:282)](https://quran.com/2/282).

Comment: Even if there's a difference between the scholars on the amount of verses in surat al-Muzzamil it doesn't apply to this verse (so it is basically one single verse in all counts).