# What is this punctuation mark?

Tags: quran, quran-recitation

[image]

What do I do when this punctuation mark comes in the Quran

Answer (score 1):

The ۵ indicates a period (end of the current verse and start of a new verse) in non-kufic recitations. That لا usually indicates that one must not pause here, but since this is on a period there is difference on whether one should or should not pause and either way is correct. See [What's the meaning of khamsa below jim waqf sign?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/52488/)